# Negative weights and biases in siamese keras model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, activation-function

I try to train a siamese model in keras. I use a really simple encoder with only covnets to encode a 32x32 RGB picture into a feature vector. The encoder encodes two pictures A and B. Then a MLP compares the two vectors and computes a score between 0 and 1 which is should be high if A and B are of the same class and low if they are not.

I used relu as the activation function on all layers but the model only learned to encode everything into a 0-vector. I switched to 'tanh' and saw that a lot of weight and biases, and also the entries in the feature-vector are negative. So i now understand why with relu everything was zero. But how come i get negative values? The input is positive, output as well  and y-values are 0 or 1. I think there is something wrong with my model.

It doesn't perform very well either. It gets to around 60% accuracy.

Here is my model:

```
def model():
    initializer = keras.initializers.random_uniform(minval=0.0001, maxval=0.001)
    enc = Sequential()
    enc.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer))
    enc.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer))
    enc.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer))
    enc.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer))
    enc.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer))
    enc.add(Conv2D(4, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer))
    enc.add(Flatten())

    input1 = Input((32, 32, 3))
    # enc.build((1,32,32,3))
    #  enc.summary()
    input2 = Input((32, 32, 3))

    enc1 = enc(input1)
    enc2 = enc(input2)

    twin = concatenate([enc1, enc2])
    twin = Dense(64, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer)(twin)
    twin = Dense(32, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=initializer)(twin)
    twin = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer=initializer)(twin)

    twin = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=twin)
    twin.summary()

    twin.compile(optimizer=adam(0.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["acc"])
    return twin
```

Edit: I found out it was all good. Just my data was bad. I had only 1/10's samples of one class compared to the others. Oversampling didn't help. I removed the class from the dataset for now. Its working. I might add the class back in with augmented copies as additional samples and see how it goes.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having negative values in feature vectors, weights, biases. Not sure why you think its wrong.

Comment: I encode the same data with an autoencoder which has only positive entries. It performs much better than this model. I also tried a different approach for the comparison (L1-distance) but it also does not work well.

Maybe the negative values are not the problem, it just strikes me as odd.